# Having trouble getting rsync to restore data to my PC

Tags: rsync

My Linux Mint 20.2 computer is set up with data in each of these:

```
/home/user/Desktop
/home/user/Documents
/home/user/Pictures
/home/user/Videos
/home/user/Downloads
/home/user/GitHub
```

I back up this data using: `rsync -ac --info=progress2 --delete --keep-dirlinks /home/user/{Downloads,Desktop,Documents,GitHub,Pictures,Videos} /media/user/<DRIVE-NAME>`. `<DRIVE-NAME> might be` TOSHIBA-EXT`or`CRUCIALX6-2`; I have a couple external drives so that's the basic syntax. This works great; brand new and altered/changed/updated local files get backed up to the external drive so the external drive always has the most recent, and anything I've deleted locally is deleted from the external drive. This is my desired behavior.

I recently attempted to use: `rsync -ac --delete --keep-dirlinks --exclude='GitHub' /media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT /home/user` to try and restore my data, excluding `/GitHub`, from the external drive `TOSHIBA-EXT` to my local storage. I was disappointed to find `/home/user/Documents` wasn't up-to-date.

Turns out, it created `/home/user/TOSHIBA-EXT`, with the directories `Downloads`, `Desktop`, `Documents`, `Pictures`, and `Videos` inside. So I hit up the rsync man pages.

These didn't work:

`rsync -ac --delete --keep-dirlinks --exclude='GitHub' /media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT/{Downloads, Desktop, Documents, Pictures, Videos} /home/user/{Downloads, Desktop, Documents, Pictures, Videos}` - Appeared to hang.

`rsync -ac --delete --keep-dirlinks --exclude='GitHub' /media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT/{Downloads, Desktop, Documents, Pictures, Videos} /home/user/` - Appeared to hang.

`rsync -ac --delete --keep-dirlinks --exclude='GitHub' /media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT/ /home/user/{Downloads, Desktop, Documents, Pictures, Videos}` - Appeared to hang.

`rsync -ac --delete --keep-dirlinks --exclude='GitHub' /media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT/ /home/user/` - Failed with errors like: `cannot delete non-empty directory: .local/shore/Trash/files/Videos}/TOSHIBA-EXT`. The other errors are similar.

`rsync -acr --delete --keep-dirlinks --exclude='GitHub' /media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT/ /home/user/` - Returned errors similar to above.

`rsync -acr --delete --keep-dirlinks --exclude='GitHub' /media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT/ /home/user/` - Created `/home/user/TOSHIBA-EXT`.

The behavior I'm after is:

| Copy contents of these directories | Get restored to: |
| --- | --- |
| `/media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT/Desktop` | `/home/user/Desktop` |
| `/media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT/Documents` | `/home/user/Documents` |
| `/media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT/Pictures` | `/home/user/Pictures` |
| `/media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT/Videos` | `/home/user/Videos` |
| `/media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT/Downloads` | `/home/user/Downloads` |

I've been reading the rsync man pages and duckduckgo results, but I think I need some help.

How do I need to change my restore command to accomplish the restore behavior above?

Comment: someone posted this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the restore you were missing a trailing slash on your source path. The documentation (`man rsync`) does say this, but it's a long page and easy to miss:

> You can think of a trailing `/` on a source as meaning "copy the contents  of this directory"  as  opposed  to "copy the directory by name", but in both cases the attributes of the containing directory are transferred to the containing directory on the  destination.

You should also remove the `-c` (`--checksum`) flag. It adds no value here and significantly slows the speed of the backup.

Therefore, your backup should look like this, which creates directories `Downloads`, `Desktop`, `Documents`, etc in the destination:

```
rsync -avi --delete /home/user/{Downloads,Desktop,Documents,GitHub,Pictures,Videos} /media/user/<DRIVE-NAME>
```

And the corresponding full restore would look like this, where I've added `u` (`--update`) to avoid updating files that are newer on the target, and removed `--delete` so that we avoid deleting directories and files that weren't backed up:

```
rsync -auvi /media/user/<DRIVE-NAME>/ /home/user/
```

Comment: How would I exclude the GitHub directory? `--exclude 'GitHub' ahead of the source path?

Comment: Figured out how to exclude the GitHub directory: rsync -au --info=progress2 --keep-dirlinks /media/user/<DRIVE-NAME>/{Downloads,Desktop,Documents,Pictures,Videos} /home/<USER-NAME>/

Comment: Sorry. This would be for the restore (from external drive to PC). I don't remember where `--keep-dirlinks` came from, but if it's not necessary I'd be happy to remove it.

Comment: Your solution would work (but with lots of directories it could get messy). An alternative to your solution could be `rsync -auvi --exclude '/GitHub/' /media/user/<DRIVE-NAME>/ /home/user/`

Comment: that worked, thank you! Someone was telling me to put an `--exclude` statement before both the source and destination paths, like this: `--exclude GitHub --exclude /media/user/TOSHIBA-EXT --exclude /home/user`, and that didn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

someone posted this. I think you just have an extra / at end.

Trailing slashes matter
When using "/" at the end of source, rsync will copy the content of the last folder.
When not using "/" at the end of source, rsync will copy the last folder and the content of the folder.
Note: The trailing slash (/) on the source directory modifies the behavior of the rsync command.

but I still often have to run my script and check if it works.
My data is in a partition mounted at /mnt/data and has all my folders like Documents, Music, etc.
Flash drive typically automounted in /media/fred/data256 as its partition is labeled as data256.

this is my restore:

```
rsync -aruvP /media/fred/data256/Documents /mnt/data
```

This is my copy to 256GB flash drive:

```
rsync -aruvlP --delete /mnt/data /media/fred/data256
```

I do not copy all folders with my 128GB flash drive

```
rsync -aruvP --delete /media/fred/data128/Documents /mnt/data
rsync -aruvP --delete /mnt/data/Documents /media/fred/data128
```